# Create TBase objects from Thrift-generated classes in Scala

Tags: scala, binary, thrift, scrooge

I have some Scala classes I generated with Thrift (Scrooge). Now I need to somehow instantiate those as TBase class, b/c the [TSerializer](http://people.apache.org/%7Ethejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/TSerializer.html) class needs this as an input

This is my approach:

```
  def createTestBinary(): String = {
    val proto = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory
    val err = new ClientError{}
    val binary = new TSerializer().serialize(err)
    ""
  }
```

ClientError is the generated class. How can I instantiate it or wrap it as a TBase member?

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `TSerializer`, that's for "vanilla" thrift, not for scrooge-generated classes. 
You need to do something like this instead:

```
val transport = TMemoryBuffer(1024) // or whatever 
err.write(new TBinaryProtocol(transport))
val binary = transport.getArray
```

Answer (score 0):

for scrooge-generated classes you can use  JsonThriftSerializer:

```
import com.twitter.scrooge.JsonThriftSerializer
val serializer = JsonThriftSerializer(<scrooge-generated-classes>._codec)
Json.toJson(serializer.toString(<scrooge-generated-classes>))
```